# Windows 7 cmd: UTF-8 dots appear as blocks. chcp 65001 makes no difference. What is the issue?

Tags: cmd, utf-8, windows-7

What I'm seeing:

[image: The issue at hand]

As show above, the utf-8 "dots" that should be appearing are being replaced by blocks. I read elsewhere that chcp 65001 might be a solution, but it yields no results nor differences.

This is what it should look like:

[image: Preferable result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to Windows 7, but I could reproduce your problem on Windows 10 when running **gtop** from the Command prompt. I tried several different fonts in the Command window, but none of them fixed the issue.

Here's an example of the problem when using **Courier New**:

[image: gtopBad]

Although this is not a bug with **gtop** itself, there is a closed issue associated with it. See "[Windows Command Prompt Font Support #21](https://github.com/aksakalli/gtop/issues/21)". The issue is resolved by downloading the **Iosevka** font, installing it, and setting it as the font for the Command window.

Once **Iosevka** font is being used in the Command window, blocks are replaced by dots in gtop's graphs:

[image: gtopGood]

Notes:

- I did not change the code page to 65001. Everything worked using my default code page (437).
- In [that issue report](https://github.com/aksakalli/gtop/issues/21), section 2 ("*Add Iosevka to Command Prompt*") details the use of **regedit**. I skipped that step and everything still worked. Perhaps it is required on some other Windows version(s), but it is not necessary on Windows 10.
- [**Iosevka** is a monospaced narrow font](https://typeof.net/Iosevka/), and seems fine for general use as the Command window's font.